# Using for in with Safari and Javascript (last key value is set to map)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I have an array with a length of 3.

Like this:

```
var numbers = [4, 5, 6];
```

and I want to use `for .. in` to loop through an array ([**Mozilla says:** *Note: for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order is important.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)). But this issue isn't about index order, it's about the last key value showing up as `map` in Safari.

So I created a test function below:

```
var test = function(array) {
  var arr = array.slice(0);

  for(var key in arr){
    console.log(key);
  }
}
```

Safari returns `0`, `1`, `2`, `map`.

Chrome returns `0`, `1`, `2`.

### Safari

[image: safari]

---

### Chrome

[image: chrome]

So why does Safari iterate a 4th time with a key of `map` and chrome doesn't? Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: The link you included already answer the question you ask, please carefully read the passage to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (x in array)` iterates all iterable properties of `array`.  It does not iterate only array elements which is exactly why you should not use that form for iterating only array elements.

Apparently, you have a browser version that has `.map` as an iterable property of the array object.  If you just iterate as arrays are supposed to be iterated with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

then you won't have this issue because this will iterate only array elements, not all iterable properties.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, that makes a lot of sense!